# Apex: change datetime field to 8am the next day

Tags: apex, date, datetime

I'm trying to change the value of a `Datetime` instance to 8am the next day. Going to the next day is fine:

```
Datetime.valueOf(lead.Follow_Up_Date_Time__c).addDays(1);
```

But how can I change the time to 8am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addHours()` and many other datetime specific methods, or if you don't know the current hour, your can use something like:

```
datetime.newInstance(lead.Follow_Up_Date_Time__c.year(), lead.Follow_Up_Date_Time__c.month(), lead.Follow_Up_Date_Time__c.day() + 1, 8, 0, 0);
```

For more information:  [Datetime Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

Comment: That kinda works but goes _back_ a day and into the PM?

Comment: What timezone are you in? try `newInstanceGmt()`.

Comment: Ah yep, timezone was my fault. Thanks for your answer!